# Android - create thumbnail from video

Tags: android, thumbnails, video-thumbnails

I'm developing an app that user can upload videos from his media storage.
The video is saved in Firebase Storage.
After it i want to show all the videos in recyclerview (all the videos that the user uploaded).

I want to show a thumbnail for each video, is it possibale to do?

if yes, how shall i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `createVideoThumbnail` method in `ThumbnailUtils` class.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail

Comment: thats it? just use createVideoThumbnail method? im kinda new, do you have more spesific code or video so i can check it?